# Is it possible to display the spoken words on screen with NVDA similar to VoiceOver?

Tags: voiceover, screen-readers, nvda

Apple's VoiceOver displays the spoken text in the bottom left corner of the screen as it read it.

Is this an option that can be turned on with NVDA on Windows?

Answer (score 5):

We have an option in nvda i.e "speech viewer". 
But it will show all the speech history also with the current announcing word or sentence as the latest.

Right click >> Tools >> Speech viewer

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Windows, where do you Right click to get to tools?

Comment: @bantuist - right click on the nvda icon in the system tray (bottom right).